# How to offset rows by variable number of rows

Tags: r, dplyr

With the data like below:

```
data <- structure(list(seq_grp = 1:40, n_offset = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 1, 7, 6, 5, 
4, 3, 2, 1, 1, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2)), row.names = c(NA, -40L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I would like to create a new column where the values in following rows would have the values of `seq_grp` but with offset of length defined by `n_offset`. I hoped that `dplyr::mutate(new = dplyr::lead(seq_grp, n = n_offset))` would work, but `lead` accepts only scalars.

Answer (score 2):

An option with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
data %>%
   mutate(new_sq = seq_grp[row_number() + n_offset])
```

Comment: Would not work under following scenario:

`tibble(x = 1:100, offset = -1) %>% 
  mutate(x_new = x[row_number() + offset])`

Answer (score 1):

It's not `dplyr` but with just `baseR` you could do this:

```
data$new_sq <- data$seq_grp[1:nrow(data) + data$n_offset]

data$new_sq

[1]  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 14 14 14 15 18 18 18 19 20 21 24 24 24 25 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 33 NA NA NA NA
[37] NA NA NA NA
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer similar to @akrun but handles edge case where index with offset does not exist.

```r
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(1234)
df <- tibble(x = letters, offset = c(-1, sample(-3:3, 24, replace = TRUE), 1))

offset_pos <- function(x, offset){
  seq_x <- seq_along(x)
  pos_start <- seq_x  + offset
  pos_final <- if_else(pos_start %in% seq_x, pos_start, NA_real_)
  x[pos_final]
}

df %>% 
  mutate(new_x = offset_pos(x, offset))
#> # A tibble: 26 x 3
#>    x     offset new_x
#>    <chr>  <dbl> <chr>
#>  1 a         -1 <NA> 
#>  2 b         -3 <NA> 
#>  3 c          1 d    
#>  4 d          1 e    
#>  5 e          1 f    
#>  6 f          3 i    
#>  7 g          1 h    
#>  8 h         -3 e    
#>  9 i         -2 g    
#> 10 j          1 k    
#> # ... with 16 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2019-09-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>